# Kendo ui grid hierarchical

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid with columns Name and Action (delete/edit). I have for example :

Parent1 - row 1
Girl1 -row 2
Boy1 row 3

Parent2 
Girl2 
Boy2

parent 3
parent 4

When I click on row 1 row 2 and row 3 should colaps. What is the best approach?

All data are comming from database

```
 dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Parents"
                            },
```

For colapsable rows should I make a template `<table>` and add the styles from grid table in order to look the same like the grid rows ?How am I going to display?...After column ID?... Should I add in the grid all the data: partens and children and hide the children row?... and add them in the kendo template ?

Comment: I think you need a kendo hierarchical grid. Have a look at this: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/hierarchy.html